# Anonymous blog posts and comments?

Tags: user-profile, blog, anonymous-authentication

We have an HR blog on the SharePoint and would like everyone to post and comments, issues or feedback on it. However, we want it to say annonymous for the user that posted rather than the actual username. Is there any way we could do this?

Right now what we are doing is using a user account called 'Feedback' that everyone can log into SharePoint with and post on the blog. Problem with this approach is that people forget about logging back into the 'Feedback' account to post comments.

Is there any better way to anonymize a user that is posting a comment or blog post? Or event anonymize a user that is posting on a site? What are your guys' thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: Anyone? Right now were just using another account but users often forget to log in so I don't think its the best solution....

Answer (score 0):

I have heard this requirement several times voiced in different ways. Without going into all the reasons why I don't like this policy... :) I'll say, it's hard.

A few approaches we've tried with varying degrees of success include, a workflow on the comments list that copies the comment and deletes the original (not anonymous because you can go to the recycle bin.) You can also write a custom form and handler that posts as the system account.

No one is truly anonymous in SharePoint.

Matt

Comment: Thats what I was worried about. I was also thinking, since I've recently played around with Event Receivers, would there be a way to change the author name to anonymous in ItemAdding for example?